# Java JOGL JOML Matrix Stack no funciona la animación

Tags: java, jogl

Estaba viendo un libro de Programación para gráficos 3D en Java con JOGL y JML, y el ejercicio que propone el libro se trata de animar una pirámide y dos cubos, como si la pirámide fuese el sol y los cubos la tierra y la luna respectivamente utilizando Matrix Stack.

He probado a animar sin Matrix Stack y me ha funcionado bien, pero con Matrix Stack no logro hacer que se mueva, si alguien puede echar un vistazo al programa y ver que falla.

Pongo el código completo para que se pueda probar.

Gracias de antemano.

```
package code;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.lang.Math;

import java.nio.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLContext;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_LEQUAL;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL2ES2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL2ES2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

import org.joml.*;


public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener
{
    /**
     *  Atributos privados
     */
    private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    
    private int renderingProgram;
    private int vao[] = new int[1];
    private int vbo[] = new int[2];
    
    private float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
    
    // allocate variables used in display() function, so that they won’t need to be allocated during rendering
    private FloatBuffer vals = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(16);    // utility buffer for transferring matrices
    private Matrix4f pMat = new Matrix4f();     // perspective matrix    
    private Matrix4fStack mvStack = new Matrix4fStack(5);
    
    private int mvLoc, projLoc;
    private float aspect;
    
    private final float startTime;
    
        
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Code()
    { 
        setTitle("Chapter 4 - Matrix Stack");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocation(400, 50);
        
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(myCanvas);
        
        Animator animtr = new Animator(myCanvas);
        animtr.start();
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Métodos públicos
     */
    @Override public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    { 
       GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
       
       renderingProgram = createShaderProgram("vertShader.glsl", "fragShader.glsl");
       
       setupVertices();
       
       cameraX = 0.0f; 
       cameraY = 0.0f; 
       cameraZ = 10.0f;
    }
    
    @Override public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    { 
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
                
        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
        
        // get references to the uniform variables for the MV and projection matrices
        mvLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
        projLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "proj_matrix");
        
        // build perspective matrix. This one has fovy = 60, aspect ratio matches the screen window.
        // Values for near and far clipping planes can vary as discussed in Section 4.9
        aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        pMat.setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, false, pMat.get(vals));
        
        double elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        double tf = elapsedTime / 1000.0;
        
        // push view matrix onto the stack
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.translate(-cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ);
        
        // ---------- Pyramid == Sun ------------------
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);            // Sun position
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.rotate((float)tf, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    // sun’s rotation on its axis
        
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvStack.get(vals));
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);       // draw the sun
        mvStack.popMatrix();                        // remove the sun’s axial rotation from the stack
        
        //------------ cube == planet ------------------------
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.translate((float)Math.sin(tf)*4.0f, 0.0f, (float)Math.cos(tf)*4.0f); // planet moves around sun
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.rotate((float)tf, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // planet axis rotation
        mvStack.scale(0.50f, 0.50f, 0.50f);
        
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvStack.get(vals));
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // draw the planet
        mvStack.popMatrix(); // remove the planet’s axial rotation from the stack
        
        //--------- smaller cube == moon ---------
        mvStack.pushMatrix();
        mvStack.translate(0.0f, (float)Math.sin(tf)*2.0f, (float)Math.cos(tf)*2.0f); // moon moves around planet
        mvStack.rotate((float)tf, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // moon’s rotation on its axis
        mvStack.scale(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f); // make the moon smaller

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvStack.get(vals));
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // draw the moon
        // remove moon scale/rotation/position, planet position, sun position, and view matrices from stack
        mvStack.popMatrix(); mvStack.popMatrix(); mvStack.popMatrix(); mvStack.popMatrix();  
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Code();
    }
    
    @Override public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) { }
    @Override public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }  
    
    
    /**
     * Métodos privados
     */
    private void setupVertices()
    {
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        
        // 36 vertices of the 12 triangles making up a 2 x 2 x 2 cube centered at the origin
        float[ ] cubePositions =
        {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f
        };
        
        // pyramid with 18 vertices, comprising 6 triangles (four sides, and two on the bottom)
        float[ ] pyramidPositions =
        {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // front face
             1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // right face
             1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // back face
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // left face
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, // base – left front
             1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f // base – right back
        };
        
        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);
       
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);   // cubePositions
        FloatBuffer cubeBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(cubePositions);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeBuf.limit()*4, cubeBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);   // pyramidPositions
        FloatBuffer pyrBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(pyramidPositions);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyrBuf.limit()*4, pyrBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    
    private int createShaderProgram(String vertFile, String fragFile)
    {
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        
        final String workingPath = "src/code/";
        
        String vshaderSource[ ] = readShaderSource(workingPath + vertFile);     
        String fshaderSource[ ] = readShaderSource(workingPath + fragFile);
        
        int vShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(vShader, vshaderSource.length, vshaderSource, null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(vShader);
        
        int fShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(fShader, fshaderSource.length, fshaderSource, null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(fShader);
        
        int vfprogram = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, vShader);
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, fShader);
        gl.glLinkProgram(vfprogram);
        
        gl.glDeleteShader(vShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fShader);
        
        return vfprogram;
    }
    
    private String[] readShaderSource(String filename)
    {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc;
        
        try
        {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("IOException reading file: " + e);
            return null;
        }
        
        while (sc.hasNext())
            lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        
        String[ ] program = new String[lines.size()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
            program[i] = (String) lines.get(i) + "\n";
        
        return program;
    }
}
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

out vec4 varyingColor;

void main(void)
{ 
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    varyingColor = vec4(position, 1.0) * 0.5 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 430

in vec4 varyingColor;

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{ 
    color = varyingColor;
}
```

Comment: He estado mirando y experimentando y el problema reside en la gestión que realiza el programa sobre el tiempo transcurrido, pero no termino de dar con la clave correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

El problema estaba en como se mide el tiempo, para solucionarlo por un lado he utilizado las variables `elepsedTime` y `tf` para la translación, sin tener en cuenta el `startTime`.

```
elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
tf = elapsedTime / 1000;
```

Para la rotación he creado una nueva variable de tipo double `double rtr;` que al final de `display()` se incrementa `rtr += 0.05;`

Probablemente no sea lo más elegante, pero funciona. Si alguien sabe una mejor forma de hacerlo, por favor, que lo comparta.